# How to make operator= works when creating a construcor c++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, constructor, operator-overloading

I am testing with a custom list (array) class and, generally, it works well.

It works when I use code like this:

```
List<int> list;
list = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
for(auto x : list) {
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

However, when I try the following I get an error:

```
List<int> list = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

This will take the list's items as parameters of a constructor and give me error. How I can make the `operator=` function work when creating the constructor?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class List {
private:
unsigned int l_size = 0;
T* list = new T[l_size];
public:
List(unsigned int size = 0) {
    resize(size);
}
void resize(unsigned int size) 
{
    List<T> old_list = *this;
    l_size = size;
    list = new T[l_size];
    for(int i = 0; i < old_list.size(); i++) {
        list[i] = old_list[i];
    }
}
T& operator[](int pos) {
    return list[pos];
}
template <unsigned int N>
void operator=(const T(&list)[N]) {
    resize(N);
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    this->list[i] = list[i];
    }
}
unsigned int size() {
    return l_size;
}
T* begin() {
    return &list[0];
}
T* end() {
    return &list[l_size];
}
};

int main() {

List<int> list;
list = {1,2,3,4,4,5};
for(auto x : list) {
    cout << x << endl;
}
/* The output is
1
2
3
4
4
5

This works fine.
*/

List<int> list2 = {0,9,8,7,6,4};
//This is taking the list elements a parameters of constructor so when i type like this it will give me an error. how i can make the operator= works when creating the constructor?

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `operator=` should receive the same input as a copy constructor, i.e., a const reference to an instance of your class (in your case, `const List<T>&`).

Comment: Give your List class an init-list constructor: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list

Comment: In `List<int> list = {1,2,3,4,5,6};`, `operator=` is not use, only constructors are used (from initializer_list, and (before C++17) move/copy constructor)).

Answer (score 1):

When a declaration statement has an initializer (as in your `List<int> list2 = { 0,9,8,7,6,4 };` line), it is not considered an *assignment* but, rather, calls the relevant *constructor* for the type (if there is one).<sup>1</sup>

Your `List` class doesn't have a constructor that takes a `std::initializer_list` argument, so you need to add one. Something like this:

```cpp
    List(const std::initializer_list<T>& list) {
        size_t N = list.size(), i = 0;
        resize(N);
        for (auto& data: list) this->list[i++] = data;
    }
```

(You'll also need a `#include <initializer_list>` line in your source.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Your `List<int> list2 = { 0,9,8,7,6,4 };` is equivalent to the more explicit constructor-based syntax, `List<int> list2{ 0,9,8,7,6,4 };` (dropping the `=` token); many modern C++ programmers have a strong preference for the latter.